# Hibernate: contains isn't called when you invoke List.contains

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

***What I have:***

I have one-to-many relationship between Person and Adress entities.

```
@Entity
class Person {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private List<Address> addresses;
  ...
}
```

***What I need:***

I need to check if specific address has been modified. So, I do

```
if (address.getId() != 0 && !person.getAddresses().contains(address)) { 
//this address has already been persisted but one (or more) of it fields have been modified
//than it has been modified
}
```

***What a problem***

Hibernate DOESN'T CALL equals() method of Address entity! Seems it just compare entity's ids.

***Question:***

How could force List.contains use overriden equals() method?

***EDIT***

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;

    if (!(o instanceof VacancyComment))
        return false;

    VacancyComment vc = (VacancyComment) o;

    if (!(vc.getId() == this.getId()))
        return false;

    if (!vc.getAuthor().equals(this.getAuthor()))
        return false;

    if (!vc.getCreated().equals(this.getCreated()))
        return false;

    if (!vc.getText().equals(this.getText()))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

***Answer:***

Despite the fact I know the reason know, I still can't grasp it. So the reason is:
Address collection has a LAZY fetch type, means Hibernate didn't have time to load it.

*But there is still one question:*

It is easy to figure out why it doesn't call equals() method, BUT WHY that lazy-collection's contains() method always returns true??

Comment: Have you implemented the equals and hashCode methods for Address class?? If yes, post your code here.

Comment: Hibernate has nothing to do with the method call `list.contains`. if `equals` is implemented properly, it will return true.

Comment: only equals() method. Do I need hashCode()?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: yes, but it doesn't explain why my equals method isn't called at all/ never.

Comment: Try debugging your code and set break point in equals method. If you can post your equals method, it would help us identify the reason behind it.

Comment: Yes ) I've created my topic only after checking it in debug. You can see my equals method in _EDIT_ section of my question

Answer (score 0):

What about overriding the `equals()` method for an `Address` class and then use the normal `ArrayList#contains()` as that uses the `equals()` to evaluate if two objects are the same.